# Formatting an excel spreadsheet with 6 columns into one single column

Tags: excel, transpose

I need to change the format of an excel spreadhseet from six columns to one, where each event is stacked on top of the other in date order.
At present I have:

Event name, date, city, country, price, website

And I need

Event name

Date

City

Country

Price

Website

for all 101 events on the list. Can anyone help!?

Thanks

Danny

Comment: I suspect the answer by Roobert-P is not going to meet your need.  If not you will need to provide more information about the data, and possibly rethink your question. How would you keep your data grouped and sort it by date, without manaually making everychange?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below Screen shot, Hope this Helps.

Before Copying Sort Date Column.

[image]